# Discord py. Не получается вывести имя гильдии. Помогите пожулайста

Tags: discord, discord.py

Миллион разных способов перепробовал, но не получается. Помогите пожалуйста чтобы оно показывало название сервера.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload,ctx):

    post_id = config.MESSAGE_ID
    role_id = config.ID_ROLE

    role_name = "Участник"
    message_id = payload.message_id
    author = payload.member
    if(message_id == post_id):
        role = disnake.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, id=config.ID_ROLE)
        await author.add_roles(role)
        print(format(payload.member) + ' got the role:' + '\''+role_name+'\'!')
        guild = str(ctx.guild)
        await ctx.author.send('Name guld:' + guild)
```

Comment: вы для начала определитесь с заголовком и телом вопроса. а то там написано разное.

Comment: СРОЧНО делают на других ресурсах. А тут такие ОРЫ раздражают и они ни к чему

Comment: Я понимаю, сори.

Answer (score 0):

Полный список всех атрибутов и методов `Guild` читайте [здесь](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#guild). Преобразование при помощи `str()` не нужно.

```py
ctx.guild.name
```